# C# call java.exe and get result from cmd wrong

Tags: c#, java, console

I want to using C# process to get result from Command Prompt. The command is "java HelloWorld 1" (I have been build it to HelloWorld.class file using **"javac HelloWorld.java"**)

The java code:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public HelloWorld() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {    System.out.println("STARTED");
        try {
            int param = Integer.parseInt(args[0].toString());
            if (param == 1) {
                System.out.println("BASE 64!");
            } else if (param == 2) {
                System.out.println("MD5!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("INPUT NOT MATCH!");
            }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            System.out.println("NO INPUT - ERROR");
        }
    } }
```

and The C# code:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_25\\bin\\java.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "HelloWorld 1";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();
    string strOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

But the strOutput is "". 
Can you give me the solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The most likely thing is that java cannot find your `HelloWorld.class` file.

In that case, it will write to the standard error something like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

and then a stack trace.

And it will not write anything to the standard output

I suggest you do two things:

1) read from standard error as well and see what that says

2) add a classpath argument prior to the class file

```
 p.StartInfo.Arguments = " -cp C:\\code\\myapp HelloWorld 1";
```

(Obviously substituting in the correct path to the folder that contains HelloWorld.class)

Comment: I used cmd "javac HelloWorld.java" to build the HelloWorld.class, and i change the code like: p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_25\\bin\\java.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = " -cp C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_25\\bin\\ HelloWorld 1"; but it does not run

Comment: is HelloWorld.class in C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_25\\bin\\  ?  The cp option needs to point to where the class file is.

Comment: @QuangVinh the class path should not be to the executable (java.exe) but to the location of your compiled java code. Ie the path to HelloWorld

Comment: i added the code "p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory", so it works right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to set your process start info to the location of HelloWorld:

```
ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java.exe");
pInfo.Arguments = = "HelloWorld";
pInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\JavaFiles";
pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process javaProc = Process.Start(pInfo);
string output = javaProc.StandarOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

EDIT: I just realized your `p` was a Process object.  `WorkingDirectory` is a property of `ProcessStartInfo`

This is assuming that C:\JavaFiles\HelloWorld.class and C:\JavaFiles\HelloWorld.java exists.  You should also follow Greg's advice and read StandardError, as it will help you troubleshoot future problems

Comment: Thank you Tung, i don't have p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory, so it does not work. Are you Vietnamese? Give me your Yahoo to become friend :)